# getGeneLengthAndGCContent in EDASeq complains about "Ensemble gene ID"

Tags: ensembl

I am trying to use the `getGeneLengthAndGCContent` function from the `EDASeq` library to retrieve gene lengths for c. elegans. I retrieved Ensemble gene ids from Biomart for c.elegans and I'm using those as input to getGeneLengthAndGCContent (I picked "ensemble_gene_id" from the filters of the worm annotation Mart). Here's an example of how I'm trying to use the function:

```
getGeneLengthAndGCContent("WBGene00001042", org, mode=c("biomart", "org.db"))
```

When I try to run this, I get

```
Error in getGeneLengthAndGCContent("WBGene00001042", org, mode = c("biomart",  : 
  Only ENTREZ or ENSEMBL gene IDs are supported.
```

Comment: @ATpoint oh that's weird why does BioMart list it as such?

Comment: @ATpoint also when I look at Ensembl I don't find any other identifier for a gene of c elegans (here's an example http://uswest.ensembl.org/Caenorhabditis_elegans/Gene/Summary?g=WBGene00001042;r=III:5415556-5419565;t=W03A5.7.1). Could you guide me as to where to find those other ids?

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong.

Comment: @ATpoint so WBGene00001042 is indeed the Ensembl id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/444909/). It uses `getGeneLengthAndGCContent` but changes a small part of the function.